# Shell: Check If File Exists When Changing Format

Tags: bash, shell, unix, exists

I'm trying to write a script that, when run, renames all .htm files in the directory to .html for a server. NO PROBLEM!

```
for file in *.htm ; do mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\.\)htm/\1html/'` ; done
```

However, if there is a .html equivalent of a file already, it should print out "$file.html already converted - contacted administrator" and exit with status 1

I've tried using -mv and exists, but no cigar. Any help appreciated.

Comment: When `$file` is ending with `.htm`, the corresponding html file is `${file}l`.

Comment: When only one file has a `html` version, do you want the others to be renamed before the `exit 1`?

Answer (score 1):

You should first check for the file, then try to rename it by moving.

Something like this should suffice:

```
for file in *.htm; do
  [ -f "${file%.*}.html" ] && mv "${file}" "${file%.*}.html" || printf "%s.html already converted - contacted administrator" "${file%.*}"
done
```

Note that also without any substitution you can just do `mv "${file}" "${file}l"`.

Note that if do not use an amministrative user it is safer using an `if-then-else` as follows:

```
for file in *.htm; do
  if [ -f "${file%.*}.html" ]; then
    mv "${file}" "${file%.*}.html"
  else
    printf "%s.html already converted - contacted administrator" "${file%.*}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Great, thanks. How do I print out an error message as requested above and with exit code 1? Not sure what the && does .

Comment: Shouldn't you check `-f "${file%.*}.html`?

Comment: Please edit again: Not `if [ -f "${file}.html" ]; then` but `if [ -f "${file%.*}.html" ]; then` or `if [ -f "${file}l" ]; then`